# When does a villager from another town I asked to come to my town move in?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I want to adopt a villager from another town. After asking the villager to move into my town, when does the house plot appear in my town?

Answer (score 2):

To provide full answer, I'll just clarify a bit more of the background first.

It is possible to invite animals from other villages by speaking with them when you're in someone else's town, but the following conditions must be met in order for it to come up in conversation with them:

1. The villager you wish to invite must be about to move away, and currently in boxes (packing),
2. You must have space in your town, so you must have no more than 9 current villagers.

Assuming the above criteria is met and you successfully invite an animal, their plot will appear within 2 days (usually the next day), as long as you don't have a special event that day.

And remember to keep talking with them once they arrive to stop them moving away unexpected if they're a dream villager :D